# How to check if message has sender in Akka Actor

Tags: scala, akka, akka-actor

Sometimes messages to actors do not have a sender, for example if they are sent like this:

```scala
actorRef.tell(Message(...), Actor.noSender)
```

One use case for this is to indicate that you are not interested in a response to this `Message`.

In the `receive` method of an Actor, how can I check if the `sender()` is an actor, opposed to `noSender`?

The best I've come up with is the following test based on the actor path, but I'm not sure that I can rely on this to work in all cases and future changes, Akka cluster etc.

```
if(sender.path.elements != "deadLetters" :: Nil) ...
```

If there is no sender, I don't want the response to go to `deadLetters`, because in my system I am treating undelivered messages as a warning that something is wrong.

Is there a better and more reliable way to check if there is a sender?

Comment: Did you try sender == Actor.noSender?

Comment: Yes tried, doesn't work @texasbruce. Actor.noSender is simply and alias for `null`, but `sender()` is the `deadLetter` actor on the receiving side. Result is inequality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

```scala
val hasSender = sender != context.system.deadLetters
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally a nicer pattern is to add a `replyTo: Option[ActorRef]` to your message, so this is more explicit.

Comment: I appreciate the concept, might use it some time (upvoted). I can't mark this as an answer though because it does not address the original question. To what you are saying, using `replyTo`, would you still be able to use the `ask` pattern in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working in Java-land and needed something similar for logging senders. I'm also working within a util class that doesn't have access to the Akka context—I just have a passed ActorRef.  Went with:

```
actorRef instanceof DeadLetterActorRef ? "[no-sender]" : actorRef.path().toStringWithoutAddress()
```